# how can i count how many consonants are in a string so far i have this

Tags: c++, string

```
int countConsonant(string str, int consonant)
{
    int length = str.length();
     consonant = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if(str[i] == 'b'&& str[i] == 'c' && str[i] == 'd'&& str[i] == 'f'
                && str[i] == 'g'&& str[i] == 'h'&& str[i] == 'j' && str[i] == 'k'&& str[i] == 'l'&& str[i] == 'm'
                && str[i] == 'n'&& str[i] == 'p'&& str[i] == 'q'&& str[i] == 'r'&& str[i] == 's'&& str[i] == 't'
                && str[i] == 'v'&& str[i] == 'w'&& str[i] == 'x'&& str[i] == 'y'&& str[i] == 'z')

                consonant = consonant + 1;
        }
        return consonant;
}
```

Comment: Lol, your code basically says if str[i] is all the consonants of the alphabet at once. That's one supercharacter!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were close, but should check with logical-or `||`, not logical-and `&&` (`str[i]` simply can't be equal to two different things).

The C++03 Standard allows you to use the keywords `and` and `or` - and `not`, `xor` etc - instead of these cryptic (for new programmers) symbols, but this hasn't caught on widely - perhaps because Microsoft's compiler doesn't default to being Standard-compliant in this regard - presumably to avoid breaking existing client code that has variables, functions, types etc. with these names.  So, for portability and simplicity, many libraries and textbooks avoid these keywords too.

Another approach that might be a little more concise is to use `isalpha()` from `<cctype>` then check it's not a vowel.  Faster approaches tend to use arrays from character value to `bool`, but beware indexing outside the array due to signed character values or >=128 bit non-ASCII values.  If there's also uppercase/lowercase to consider - you may want to use `tolower()` on your character before testing it (i.e. `char c = tolower(str[i])); if (c == '...`).

Other notes: your function should:

- accept its `std::string` argument by `const` reference (i.e. `const std::string& str`) to avoid unnecessary and time-consuming copying of the value from the calling context into a separate variable local to this function.  The copying doesn't do any real functional harm, but it's unnecessary.
- make `consonant` a local variable rather than a function parameter, as any inputted value is immediately clobbered with 0, and the result it returned by the function rather than written into `consonant` (which would be impossible as it is passed by value rather than passed by pointer/reference).

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


bool isVowel(char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        {
            return true;
        }
        default:
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


bool isConsonant(char c)
{
    return !isVowel(c);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string test = "hello";
    std::size_t numVowels = std::count_if(test.begin(), test.end(), isConsonant);
    std::cout << "Number of vowels is: " << numVowels << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: isConsonant should `return !isVowel(c) && isalpha(c);`

Comment: I like the basics. But the character '=' is now a contant. But rather than a switch you could use an array of 255 indicating true/false for consonant.

Comment: @Martin: note that use of `signed char` can result in lookup to negative array indices, so it needs to be cast to `unsigned` or range-checked first (slower).  `switch` is quite nice anyway - compilers should generate pretty good code, though the space/speed tradeoff may not be the one you want.

Comment: @Tony: I am sure the writers of isalpha() and other character trait type functions etc thought of all this when they wrote their code. Yet it still remains as a lookup into a table, thus my suggestion only follows on the heals of some very reliable and highly tested code. Yes switch is fast and efficient but I bet an indexed look-up may have a slight edge (especially since it does not involve a jump which will be hard to predicate).

Comment: @Martin: yes, I'm not arguing the indexing approach (I had listed it in my answer), just saying that if implementing it yourself (which is the thrust of this question, rather than using precanned `isalpha()` etc.) then you need to consider this easily-overlooked aspect.  Indexing does tend to be faster, there's even a good chance a compiler will generate an indexed lookup from the `switch`, but it may well range-check it first so the lookup table is much smaller - saving space but wasting time.  Run-time's usually the overwhelming priority for this type of func., so an explicit table's good.

Answer (score 2):

First: `&&` will test *everything* until something returns `false` or the end is reached. What you want is `||` which will test until a condition is `true`.
Second: What is shorter? Testing for consonants or testing for vowels? Vowels of course. Just put that test in an extra function (note: I assume a valid, alphabetical input string here):

```
function is_vowel(c) : bool
  for each vowel test
    if c == that vowel
      return true
  return false
```

After that, just replace your big conditional statement with a simple `!is_vowel(str[i])`. :) And last but not least, you want to *increment* your `consonant` variable, and there is a special operator for that: the increment operator! (Cool name, huh?)

```
++consonant; // better than consonant = consonant + 1; but same result
```

Comment: For the vowel part - characters could be not vowels and not consonants!

Comment: @mrtsherman: Well, yeah, if they aren't letters.. I was assuming the OP gets a valid input string, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Look into regular expressions. It allows you to specify a list of characters to be checked for. You would check each character in the string against the list and increment your counter.

http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_regex.html

Comment: I don't think regular expressions are allowed in the OP's homework assignment.

Comment: I don't think one should attack everything with regex'... KISS.

Comment: @xeo - haha. In my mind regex is easier =). @paul regex is overkill for your hw assignment, but they are pretty awesome. If you want to expand your programming knowledge read up on them!

Answer (score 0):

For starters you are using `&&` (and) which is a logic error in this case.  You want to use `||` (or).

You can also shorten the code a great deal by checking to see if they are NOT vowels.

```
int countConsonant(string str, int consonant)
{
    int length = str.length();
    int consonant = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(!(str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'o' ||
            str[i] == 'u'))

        consonant = consonant + 1;
    }
    return consonant;
}
```

Someone else already posted an alternate form of this code as a function where you just pass in the variable you want to test.

Comment: Close. But not quite the same. The character '=' is now a constant.

Comment: @Martin You're right and I've made assumptions I shouldn't have made regarding the characters in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

size_t countConsonant(const string& s) {
    const string vowels("aeiou");
    size_t count = 0;
    for (string::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i) {
        if (vowels.find(tolower(*i)) == string::npos) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    cout << countConsonant("abcd") << endl;
}
```

Or, if you don't want non-alpha stuff to match, you can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

size_t countConsonant(const string& s) {
    const string cons("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz");
    size_t count = 0;
    for (string::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i) {
        if (cons.find(tolower(*i)) != string::npos) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    cout << countConsonant("abcd") << endl;
}
```

Comment: Second implementation's much nicer. Or you could templatise count to accept a `const char*` and instantiate for consonants or vowels or anything else as needed....

Answer (score 0):

Way overkill for this homework, but just for reference - an object-oriented approach:

```
struct Consonants
{
    bool x_[256];

    Consonants()
    {
        // constructor sets x_[i] to true or false to indicate
        // whether character with ASCII number i is a consonant...

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
            x_ = false;

        // note: ASCIIZ string finishes with NUL, so *p becomes false
        //       and for loop exits
        for (const char* p = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
                             "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"; *p; ++p)
            x_[*p] = true;
    };

    int in(const std::string& str) const
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
            if (x_[(unsigned char)str[i]])
                ++result;
        return result;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
Consonants consonants;  // create an "utility" object once

int c1 = consonants.in("hello world");   // use as often as desired
int c2 = consonants.in("goodbye cruel world");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to count how many consonants are in a string:

```
int main()
{
    char a[20];
    int consonants; 
    gets(a);
    cout<<a<<endl;
    if(a[i]>=0 && a[i]<=9)  //  consonants
    {
        consonants++;
    }
    cout<<"Total Consonats are: "<<consonants;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting code in answers, it is helpful to explain how your code solves the OP's problem. Please edit your answer to include this :)